# How can I speed up this giant query against a MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

This query goes against a single table. The table has 60 attributes called "attribute1" through "attribute60", and they are all of type:

```
varchar(255)
```

There is also a column called "brand_id" that is:

```
int(11)
```

The following key exists on the table:

```
brand_id, attribute1, attribute2, attribute3
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT distinct attribute1
from brands b inner join product_applications pa on pa.brand_id = b.id
where b.id in (1,372,373,374,375,376,378,381,452,
               453,454,455,456,457,458,461,474,476,
               544,480,563,508,512,513,516,517,519,520,521,
               522,524,525,527,528,529,533,538,539,540,542,
               546,547,548,555,556,557,642,643,644,645,646,
               647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655)
```

It takes over 10 seconds. The table has 5,735,673 rows.

This query needs to take no more than 2 seconds. I cannot figure out how to write it, or if I need some sort of alternate table structure, to do this. Can anyone offer a recommendation?

I used to use an IN in the WHERE clause, but it was recommended in another forum that this ugly way was faster because of the join. I don't really know what that means, but it IS faster, but still incredibly slow.

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                          | key                | key_len | ref       | rows  | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | range | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY            | 4       | NULL      |    60 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pa    | ref   | brand_search_index,parttype_search_idx | brand_search_index | 5       | mcp5.b.id | 57356 | Using where; Using index                  | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Ugh... Is there no way you can change this 1. to use InnoDB, and 2. to have a sane schema?

Comment: How many of the 5million rows in table PA are returned by the query if you leave the DISTINCT out of it?

Comment: How will InnoDB speed up the query? Why is that table not sane? The variation among all of the attributes is such that it results in lots of rows, and yet is not so uniform that it can be broken up relationally.

Comment: The majority of rows are returned if the distinct is left out, 5,527,525 out of a possible 5,735,673. The DISTINCT whittles the result set down to only 123. That's a lot of data to crunch through.

Comment: Is the list of IDs in the union query static?  Can you put those values in another table containing just the id column?  If nothing else, that'd be easier to maintain.

Comment: @AKWF: I asked that question to demonstrate that the DISTINCT has to do something akin to a full table scan to whittle the result set down. It doesn't have access to an index because attribute1 is in second position in your multipart key.

Comment: I have decided to stop the insanity and not believe everything I read on the interwebz, so you guys are right. I changed the query above, and now it runs in 12 seconds. When it's in cash, it's subsecond. But I have to get that 12 down to 2. Upvotes anyway for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure you need `varchar(255)` for those fields? What is the result of `SELECT * FROM product_applications PROCEDURE ANALYSE ( )`?

Comment: "Why is that table not sane?" - 60 columns in 1 table is not optimal situation.

Comment: @AKWF:  see the suggested multi-table approach in my answer. I don't think you're going to be able to attain your 2-second goal when you have a denormalized structure that results in over 5million rows when you ask for all of the attribute1 values for a set of brands. You will need to normalize the structure to reach that goal.

Comment: Let me see what kind of return I can get by cutting the field sizes in half.

Comment: bancer your recommendation about cutting those fields down to an appropriate size helped alot, I wish you put that in an answer but I upped your comments to pay you. I also ended up creating a summary table off of the first 3 attributes and that is giving me the subsecond response time I needed. Then I have enough juice to go at that big table with a bunch of attributes and it pays off quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd query, so I might be missing something, but I think you can do this with an IN clause:

```
SELECT distinct attribute1
from product_applications pa WHERE brand_id IN (1, 372, ..., 655)
```

I would think this is faster -- it's certainly cleaner -- but if not you might need to add a little detail about indexes, maybe an EXPLAIN QUERY, etc.

Comment: _maybe_ an EXPLAIN query? Never leave home without one! :-)

Comment: That's what I originally had, and the crazy way I do it above is faster. I updated my question with the results of the EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is something like this:

```
        brand...attr1......attr2..........attr3
        BRAND...CATEGORY...PRODTYPE....PRODUCT
```

e.g.

```
        DOVE....HOME.......SOAP.......dish washing liquid
```

And you want go get the distinct set of product categories for a specified list of brands. But you have over 5 million products, so it cannot be done instantly with a single table. The way this is typically handled is to have multiple related tables:

```
       BRANDS(brandid, brandname)
       CATEGORIES (categoryid, categoryname)
       PRODTYPES (prodtypeid, prodtypename)
       BRANDCATEGORIES (brandid, categoryid) EDIT: put a unique constraint on (brandid, categoryid)
       PRODUCTS(brandid, categoryid, prodtypeid, productname)
```

Then, your query would be this:

```
      select distinct categories.categoryid, categoryname
      from brands inner join categories
      on brand.brandid = brandcategories.brandid
      and categories.categoryid = brandcategories.categoryid
      where brands.brandid in ( .... )
```